# Is there a way to prevent me spending tokens until an action is called?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token, token-distribution

I am creating a smart contract but came to a halt when writing the code.

Is there a way, in a smart contract, to prevent me from spending tokens transferred to me by another user through the smart contract until another action is called that unlocks it for spending?

Comment: Do you mean EOS token or some token your smart contract has created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

1. Create a table with the user's name and whether they are allowed to spend their tokens or not.
2. Check this table in the transfer function.
3. When the appropriate action is called, update the table entry to permit transfers.

For example:

**token code**

```
ACTION transfer(eosio::name from, eosio::name to, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo){
  transfer_not_allowed_table table(contract, scope);
  eosio::check(table.find(from.value) == table.end(), "may not transfer");
  // rest of transfer code
}
```

**transfer allowed code**

```
TABLE allowed{
  eosio::name user;
  uint64_t primary_key() const{return user.value;}
};
typedef eosio::multi_index< "allowed"_n, allowed > transfer_not_allowed_table;

ACTION disallow(eosio::name user){
  transfer_not_allowed_table table(contract, scope);
  eosio::check(table.find(user) == table.end(), "already not allowed to transfer");
  table.emplace(_self, [&](auto & entry){
    entry.user = user;
  });
}

ACTION allow(eosio::name user){
  transfer_not_allowed_table table(contract, scope);
  eosio::check(table.find(user.value) != table.end(), "already allowed to transfer");
  table.erase(table.find(user.value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add handler method with annotation `[[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]]` to control token transfers. Through the handler you can check is this transfer is corresponding to the contract logic.

By the way, as I know you can change code in anyway while you have permission to that. So, if you want to make you contract 100% safe, after the code is completed you need to remove permissions. I did it by looping permission. But it's dangerous after that you cannot control contract and change code. It will live by themself.